# extracting portion of the files

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have many files as follows(input.txt) and i want to extract portion of it and want to save to another text file

```
# 
# XXX
# YYY
# ZZZ
# AAAAAA
# AAAAAA
# AAAAAAA AAAAA
# CCCCC
# EEEEE
# EEEEE
# DDDDD
# A(MN)  S(MN/SN)  D(MN/WN) FPR(OO/WW)   ER   QW   RRRR   WWWW   QQQQQ   XXXXX
#
45.0300  1.4212  1.1300  1.7716  5.0000  4.0000  0.0400  0.0100  1.0020  1.5000
85.0300  1.9235  1.9974  1.0492  5.0000  4.0000  0.0400  0.0100  1.0020  1.5000
56.0300  1.1454  1.1255  1.0902  5.0000  4.0000  0.0400  0.0100  1.0020  1.5000
78.0300  1.9434  1.0089  1.0528  5.0000  4.0000  0.0400  0.0100  1.0020  1.5000
```

I want to extract below file from the above file

```
1.1300  
1.9974
1.1255
1.0089
```

I tried

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv("input.csv")
b=a.loc[12:15]
```

It doesnot work here. Hope experts may help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
pd.read_csv('name_file.csv', comment='#', header=None, sep='\s+')[2]
```

---

Output:

```
0    1.1300
1    1.9974
2    1.1255
3    1.0089
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

---

To save this as `csv` file including the filename:

```
f = open('/tmp/y.csv', 'a')
f.write('# name_file.csv\n')
df.to_csv(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: how to append file name during save_to csv

Comment: You mean saving to CSV with pandas?

Comment: yes i want to save filename in single column

Comment: the file with `0    1.1300
1    1.9974
2    1.1255
3    1.0089
Name: 2, dtype: float64` ?